# Solution to excluding summing data if another condition is met Excel

Tags: excel

I'm having a tough time figuring out a solution to this Excel database that I need to populate the correct promotional cost in a given week from a list of prices.

I have a list of 100+ Products (I will use Coke Zero as an example) with weekly data that details whether my company has paid a retailer for a promotion in a given week or not. The database details whether my company has paid for an advertisement with there being 3 options: 1) No Ad which costs nothing, 2) a Basic Ad ($50 cost) or 3) a Premium Ad ($1000 cost). Nearly all promotions have at least a Basic Ad cost of $50, and typically we will pay for a 4 week slot. However, sometimes we will decide to upgrade one of those 4 weeks to a a Premium Ad - the catch is that we are only charged the premium rate ($1000 as opposed to Premium + Basic Ad or $1000+$50) for that specific week. I cannot amend the formatting of my data, which sometimes duplicates the same Product Code and Week on two separate rows.

The problem: I need a formula to populate the correct promotional cost in column D, being sure not to pull through the $50 Basic Ad cost if there is a Premium Ad being paid for on the same week.

Example of data:
***Spreadsheet Example:***

[image]

These promo costs are fixed, I have a table in another sheet that I can lookup the promo costs and fill the data with. Looks like the attached:

***Cost Table Example:***

[image]

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: what id row2 had Premium, row3 had Basic and row4 had None. is this possible? if yes then what are the expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A22=A2)*(WEEKDAY(B$2:B22)=WEEKDAY(B2))*(C$2:C22=$G$4))>=1,IF(MATCH(C2,$G$2:$G$4,0)=3,$H$4,0),VLOOKUP(C2,$G$2:$H$4,2,FALSE))
```

[image: screenshot]

`A$2:A22=A2` gets array of same product as `A2`
`WEEKDAY(B$2:B22)=WEEKDAY(B2)` gets array where the weekday is same as the current rows(`B2`) weekday
`C$2:C22=$G$4` gets array of type matching Premium(`G4`)

The product of these arrays gives an array that tells if there is a row in the table that has the same product, same `WEEKDAY` as the current row and Ad type is Premium. `SUMPRODUCT` gives the count of such cells. if this count is greater than equal to 1, it means this week has had a Premium Ad.

```
IF(MATCH(C2,$G$2:$G$4,0)=3,$H$4,0)
```

if current row is the one having premium, show premium cost, else 0 (because this week has a Premium ad)

```
VLOOKUP(C2,$G$2:$H$4,2,FALSE)
```

if there is not Premium Ad this week, just vlookup current type in the cost table and get the cost

Comment: Thanks mate, this is the one! Clever solution, I'm still getting my head around the flexibility of Sumproduct. Thanks again!